# SimpleCursorAdaptor ListView using an TextView and ImageView with over 400+ rows Memory Issues

Tags: android, image, memory, simplecursoradapter

Is this the best way or are there others?

I extend SimpleCursorAdapter and override getView(int position, View 
convertView, ViewGroup parent)

I retrieve my Cursor, inflate my ImageView and TextView, pull the data 
from the Cursor and populate the TextView and ImageView 
on the ImageView I store my images in the database as Blob's.

When I retrieve my Blob I pull it out as a byte[] and convert it to a

Bitmap as below:

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(img, 0, img.length);

Then I set my Bitmap on my ImageView as :

iv.setImageBitmap(bmp);

Now I can scroll down fine no issues but when I start scrolling back 
up the list I get major memory issues and sporadic jumping(from when 
the garbage collection catches up).

Can anyone tell me what the best way to accomplish this task would 
be?  Is there a way to recycle the bitmaps that aren't in view and 
when approaching them pull them and display again?

I've searched for months and tried various techniques but I'm at a 
loss to finding the one that will allow me to accomplish this task.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up moving the images to external storage and performing the same lazy loading as I tried in the prior attempts with the database and this worked.  Somehow attempting this from the database was not allowing the images to get garbaged collected.

Answer (score 0):

did you watch this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA

and read this thread: [how to clear the cached images in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929248/how-to-clear-the-cached-images-in-android)

Basically you want to recycle any images not currently visible.

Comment: I've watched the video and read the thread, however the issue remains but thank you for these they're very informative.  

I still believe there is something with the amount of images, each image is different and pulled from the database then a Bitmap created from a byte[] and set on the ImageView however it doesn't seem that they get garbage collected and their is no way to recycle them without the ListView throwing an error.